# extract value from a matrix based on some constraint

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have a Nx2 matrix (call it A) and a number K. I need to find the row such that the value in the first column is maximum and the value in the second column is < K

i.e. Max<sub>i</sub> A[i,1] s.t. A[i,2] < K

I need to extract the value in O(log N) or better, not including any pre-processing involved, i.e. the matrix can be sorted before searching for the element.

Comment: have you tried something on the above lines?

Comment: I have first sorted the matrix based on first column. Then traversed the second column looking for the first value that is less than K. But this traversing takes O(N). After any preprocessing, I want to find the row in O(lg N or better.

Comment: And what if sort by the second column?

Comment: @MBo I need max possible value of first column.

Comment: This is guiding question. Just think about this possibility and about additional memory usage

Comment: @MBo Yes, I have thought about keeping two copies of the matrix: one sorted by column 1, and the other sorted by column 2. But I can't think of a way to achieve the desired complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Sort matrix A by the second column

Walk through the matrix and write index of maximum value from start to the current row into auxillary array B

For every query  - find max row `imax` with binary search by the second column and get values from the first and the second cells of row `A[B[imax]]`